# TextView.setText(...) does not work in a loop inside the button's listener

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Let's say I have a button and a label. I want to update the label 100000 times in a loop that's in a button listener. The problem is that we do not see the process of updating the text, but only the last set value.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    generateLabel = findViewById(R.id.label);
    generateButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

    generateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                generateLabel.setText("" + i);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It looks like we have to get out from the onClick(...) method before any changes are updated to the label. So, I tried:

- running my own thread,
- invoking runOnUiThread(...),
- executing AsyncTask subclass,

but everytime I got an exception saying that I should not modify the View that comes from the original thread's view hierarchy. Even refreshing the label and making it `volatile` didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use AsyncTask but you can't update the label in doInBackground. So override onProgressUpdate.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int counter = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    counter = 0;
                    new Runner().run();
                }
            }
    );
}

public class Runner implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(counter++ < 1000) {
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.label)).setText("Counter: " + counter);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runner(), 100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This wont work for a number of reasons, the first being you are trying to update your UI 100,000 times in <~1 second.Note when you call `setText()` you are essentially telling the system to render the text you have passed. Rendering and re-rendering something 100k times in <~1second will cause your app to crash. Now if you were to say I will run this in some background thread that is also not possible as you can do UI work only on UI thread or the main thread and BG threads cannot be used for this purpose. The only way for this is to use `onProgressUpdate()` in AsyncTask but that is normally used for different purposes than this and the UI update from that method too happens on the main thread so it is essentially doing the same thing you are doing now and will certainly result in a crash.

Comment: i don't think that Wojciech Kazior mentions anywhere about <1sec

Comment: Even though he does not, the for loop will be execute 100k times in less than a second, roughly, and unless he adds a thread.sleep inside the loop the rendering call will be made 100k times in less than a second.

Comment: @shiredude95 1. But "setText" is a synchronous function, right? So it should be visible for me that the text changes from "0" to "99999" even if it takes less than 1 second. 2. The app didn't crash due to 100000 calls. 3. There's no problem for me with pausing the Thread, I can do it if that will help.

Comment: My bad I said the app will crash, for large values of i, the app will simply go into unresponsive state if you do not add some kind of delay. If you run it in a runnable as suggested by @DennisK then the code will execute without any issues albeit not as fast as you'd like.